# How fragile are microSD cards?

Tags: micro-sd-card

Especially when compared to USB flash drives

My parents tell me to be REALLY cautious with them. But I'm not sure if any convenience costs are warranted

Answer (score 4):

If you don't break them in half, or scratch the connectors like a mad man... it'll work.

[image]

Comment: We call them "connectors"; the actual data is on a chip within the plastic body.

Comment: Oh sorry. :) Just edit my answer these times. (And ty!)

Comment: What you are showing is a SD card, not a microSD... Micro SD are very, very very fragile. I have a 20% failure rate on good brand, if I manipulate them a lot. And more than 50% on no name brand. But if you insert them once and for all in there lifetime (in smartphone for ex.) its OK.

Answer (score -1):

In 2004 there was a photographer who wanted to take pictures of a bridge being blown up. The unmanned camera's didn't survive the blast but the memory cards survived:

http://www.sandisk.com/about-sandisk/press-room/press-releases/2004/2004-08-23-sandisk-compactflash-memory-card-survives-blast-that-destroys-camera---and-records-moment-of-impact

So, just by normal usage you won't break them.

Comment: That article is about CompactFlash memory, not MicroSD.

Comment: If a CompactFlash card manages to survive a blast then a MicroSD will do just as well.

Comment: years too late, but just found this QA.... SD are nowhere **near** as resilient as CF.